# How to externally add a javascript file to a JSP in a maven project?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I have a maven project with spring-mvc configurations with the hierarchy mentioned in below image. I've placed `list.js` file inside all the possible places in src folder and its sub folders but I couldn't access it from my `list.jsp` file. What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone help me to figure it out?

[image]

Comment: files that need to be served by the server go into src/main/webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static Resources like JS, CSS, Images,etc visible from webapp folder in a web application.

So, you can create js folder under `webapp` folder and place your `list.js` file inside it.

Also, you need to tell Spring to not process these static resources path.

Looks like you had defined your Spring Configuration in Java Classes i.e. `WebConfig`. You need to add below code

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
}
```

Lastly, change your path in jsp file like this

```
<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/list.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps to solve your problem.